# SQLite3 C++ Query near "CASE": syntax error

Tags: c++, sql, sqlite

Using SQLite3 C++ implementation though I believe this error is more general.
I'm simply trying to do a statement that says:

> "If the column 'lastPlayed' does not exist in the table 'Players', ALTER the table and add it to said table"

Here's my query:

```
    query = string("CASE WHEN COL_LENGTH('Players', 'lastPlayed') IS NULL ")
    +   " BEGIN "
    +   "ALTER TABLE Players "
    +   "ADD lastPlayed DATETIME DEFAULT now"
    +   " END "
    ;
```

The error:

> near "CASE": syntax error

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `CASE` statement is fine. The error is in the fact that `COL_LENGTH` is not an inbuilt function in SQLite.

What you can do to achieve your result is remove the `CASE` statement and in your code, just attempt to alter the Players table to add a lastPlayed column. Then wrap your alter statement in a try-catch block. When the column already exists, the exception will be thrown, otherwise the table will be altered successfully and you can proceed.

Comment: How very strange that I can't do it directly in the SQL query.

Answer (score 1):

Try this syntax

```
CASE 
    WHEN expr THEN expr
    WHEN expr THEN expr
    .
    .
END
```

https://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html